# Converting cases to variables in R

Tags: r, variables, case

I have a data with the format as data_format1. Based on it, I want to convert the cases to variables to get data_format2.

you can find data_format1 here:

```
ArticleID<-c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
Word<-c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
Freq<-c(2, 4, 6, 3, 2)
data_format1<-cbind(ArticleID, Word, Freq)

data_format1

     ArticleID Word Freq
[1,] "1"       "a"  "2" 
[2,] "2"       "b"  "4" 
[3,] "3"       "b"  "6" 
[4,] "3"       "c"  "3" 
[5,] "4"       "c"  "2"
```

data_format2 is given here:

```
ArticleID_t<-c(1, 2, 3, 4)
a<-c(2, 0, 0, 0)
b<-c(0, 4, 6, 0)
c<-c(0, 0, 3, 2)
data_format2<-cbind(ArticleID_t, a, b, c)
data_format2

     ArticleID_t a b c
[1,]           1 2 0 0
[2,]           2 0 4 0
[3,]           3 0 6 3
[4,]           4 0 0 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classical reshape problem - converting data from a tall format to a wide format.  The `reshape2` package is ideal for this.

**Note:** You need to convert your data into a `data.frame` first.  Remember that `cbind` will take your data and create an array, rather than a `data.frame`.  So in the solution I use `data.frame(...)` to recreate your data.

```
library(reshape2)
data_format1 <- data.frame(ArticleID, Word, Freq)
reshape2::dcast(data_format1, ArticleID~Word, sum)

  ArticleID a b c
1         1 2 0 0
2         2 0 4 0
3         3 0 6 3
4         4 0 0 2
```

See `?reshape2::dcast` for more information.

Comment: Thanks goes to Andrie. Immediately, I test your answer, and it works pretty good.